# Compare The length of two string variables inside an Expression task in SSIS

Tags: ssis, regular-expression

Hope you're doing well.
I need to compare the Length of two string variables inside an expression task in SSIS so that if they have the same length the package will execute the next step and if not it will stop
I've implemented something like this so far but it won't work

The images show My expression task and the regular expression within the
    task and the precedence constraint from the expression task to the next  step

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer
I Created a variable `@[User::Process]` with Boolean data type and
I changed the Expression to this

```
@[User::Process] = (DT_BOOL)((DT_I4) LEN( @[User::FileFormat] )==LEN( @[User::ExcelName] ) ? 1: 0)
```

And Changed the precedence constraint of the expression task to This

[image]